# Ctrl+End behavior of TVirtualStringTree

Tags: delphi, scroll, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

When user press Ctrl+End, VirtualStringTree jumps to the end vertically which is fine but also horizontally. I don't want it to go to the end horizontally. Horizontal scroll should be leaved as is.

How to tell this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `OnKeyAction` handler in the following code checks if the <kbd>CTRL + HOME</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL + END</kbd> are pressed and if so, it scrolls (only vertically) either to the top or bottom depending on what was pressed.

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualTreeKeyAction(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  var CharCode: Word; var Shift: TShiftState; var DoDefault: Boolean);
begin
  if (ssCtrl in Shift) then
  case CharCode of
    VK_HOME:
    begin
      DoDefault := False;
      VirtualTree.ScrollIntoView(VirtualTree.GetFirst, False);
    end;
    VK_END:
    begin
      DoDefault := False;
      VirtualTree.ScrollIntoView(VirtualTree.GetLast, False);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Do you want to select the node as well ? The default behavior (I have VirtualTreeView v.5.0.0, but I guess it's the same for the older versions) only scrolls into view with the content, it doesn't select the first or last node as well as code posted here do. And, do you want to scroll to the first column if you have some ?

Comment: Ok, seems you don't want to ;-)

Comment: I did both by using overloaded ScrollIntoView function. I got the idea. Thanks :)